# Komparativ, wo befindet sich als + Name oder als + Nebensatz

Tags: sentence-structure, phrase

Beim Komparativ, wo findet sich der "als + Name" bzw. "als + Nebensatz" wenn der Verb im Hauptsatz am Ende steht.

z.B.

> Zunächst muss den Experten eingeräumt werden, dass die gegenwärtig
> getroffenen Massnahmen weniger Auswirkungen auf die Arbeitslosenzahlen
> haben werden, als beim vorangehenden Erlebnis.

Oder -

> Zunächst muss den Experten eingeräumt werden, dass die gegenwärtig
> getroffenen Massnahmen weniger Auswirkungen auf die Arbeitslosenzahlen
> als beim vorangehenden Erlebnis haben werden.

Bei mir klingen beide gleichermassen korrekt, vielleicht irre ich mich.

Und was dann mit einem Nebensatz

> Zunächst muss den Experten eingeräumt werden, dass die gegenwärtig
> getroffenen Massnahmen weniger Auswirkungen auf die Arbeitslosenzahlen
> haben werden, als wir zuerst angenommen hatten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alle vier Varianten sind möglich; jedoch ist die Stellung am Satz-Ende bevorzugt, wenn es einen mittellangen oder langen Nebensatz einleitet (*end-weight principle*).

(Im ersten Satz ist übrigens das letzte Komma entbehrlich, da es sich ja nicht um einen Nebensatz handelt, sondern nur um eine nominale Erweiterung.)

Comment: Zum letzten Komma: Nicht *entbehrlich*, sondern *falsch*. Und im Übrigen im letzten Beispiel auch.